# Trazer somente a primeira ocorrência de uma regex

Tags: mysql, regex

Como buscar em uma query somente a primeira data?

Por exemplo:

> 30/09/2018 e 14/10/2018 e 21/10/2018

Gostaria de trazer somente a primeira data. Estou usando assim, `[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}`, porém traz tudo.

Quero só a primeira data. Tem 10 caracteres. Tem algum comando que posso colocar na minha regex que só aceita trazer os 10 primeiros?

Estou usando MySQL:

```
 WHERE REGEXP '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}'
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Gqd385/1

Comment: só retirar o `/g`. Tire o modificador `g`.

Comment: Tem como fazer, mas a resposta depende da linguagem que vc está usando. Clique em [edit] e adicione esaa informação, e o código que vc usou

Comment: @hkotsubo editado.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr perfeito, só que no MYSQL não trouxe registros. REGEXP '^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})';  Sabe porque?

Comment: @Rod Porque o MySQL [não suporta a sintaxe `\d`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax), somente `[0-9]`. Viu como é importante colocar todos os detalhes na pergunta desde o começo? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Talvez não seja necessário o regex:

Supondo que temos a seguinte tabela e queremos pegar a primeira data do campo descrição:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Executando o comando abaixo:

```
select left(descricao , 10) from tb_dados;
```

Teremos este resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Com regex:

```
select left(descricao,10) FROM tb_dados where descricao RLIKE('^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}');
```

Comment: Muito simples e funcional. Obrigado.

Comment: @Rod Apenas lembrando que esta solução só funciona se o campo começa com uma data. Se tiver algum texto antes e a primeira data aparece no meio do texto, aí é melhor usar `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, [como eu sugeri](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/360903/112052). Eu preferi deixar uma resposta mais geral porque não tinha ficado claro que em todos os seus casos, a data aparece no início :-)

Comment: Fiz assim: select id_tabela,titulo,data_gabarito,left(data_gabarito,10) as d_gabarito FROM tabela
where data_gabarito RLIKE('^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}') 
order by str_to_date(d_gabarito,'%d/%m/%Y') desc;

Comment: @hkotsubo porém surgiu um problema, não é possível manusear o alias d_gabarito pra fazer um refinamento no where. Queria exibir apenas exibir os registros com dois dias anteriores a data d_gabarito.

Comment: resumindo...o campo data_gabarito foi rescrito pelo regex, também foi transformado de string para data na ordenação pra exibir primeiro as antigas. Agora gostaria de pegar essas datas e só exibir as que são próxima de hoje (now). Exemplo: hoje é 07/02/2019 só exibiria registros com datas a partir de 05/02/2019. Complexo não? rs

Comment: @Rod Entendi (eu acho) :-) De qualquer forma, sugiro que nas próximas vezes coloque na pergunta os detalhes que podem influenciar na resposta. Lembre-se que os demais usuários do site não conhecem o seu sistema, e esses detalhes podem te ajudar a ter respostas mais precisas :-)

Answer (score 2):

Quando você faz uma query assim:

```
select campo from tabela where campo REGEXP '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}';
```

Você está trazendo o campo (no caso, todo o valor `30/09/2018 e 14/10/2018 e 21/10/2018`), desde que ele satisfaça a regex (ou seja, desde que ele tenha números no formato indicado). Por isso que a query traz "tudo".

Para extrair somente uma parte do campo, use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) (disponível a partir do MySQL 8). Supondo que a tabela seja:

```
create table tabela (
   campo varchar(200)
);

insert into tabela(campo) values('30/09/2018 e 14/10/2018 e 21/10/2018');
insert into tabela(campo) values('blablabla e 14/10/2018 e 21/10/2018');
insert into tabela(campo) values('nao tenho nenhuma data');
```

Podemos fazer:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(campo, '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}') from tabela;
```

E o resultado será:

```
30/09/2018
14/10/2018
null
```

O terceiro campo retorna `null`, pois o valor do campo não corresponde à regex. Você pode alterar a query para só retornar o trecho desejado quando o campo tiver uma data no formato desejado:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(campo, '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}')
from tabela where campo REGEXP '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}';
```

Agora o `where` verifica se o campo possui alguma data, e o `REGEXP_SUBSTR` extrai somente o trecho desejado. O resultado é:

```
30/09/2018
14/10/2018
```

---

Se quiser a segunda ocorrência, basta passar 2 parâmetros adicionais: a posição inicial e a ocorrência:

```
--- traz a segunda ocorrencia
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(campo, '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}', 1, 2)
from tabela where campo REGEXP '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}';
```

No caso, a posição inicial é `1`, e a ocorrência é `2` (ou seja, vou pegar a segunda data presente no campo). O resultado é:

```
14/10/2018
21/10/2018
```

Veja este exemplo rodando no [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xrj7Raj4bJU6edizXumAsb/0).

---

Mas há um porém: se tiver algo como `112/10/2019`, a regex pegará o trecho `12/10/2019`. Para evitar estes casos, você pode mudar a regex para:

```
(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}([^0-9]|$)
```

No início há o trecho `(^|[^0-9])`: o `|` [significa **"ou"**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). Portanto, este trecho significa ["início da string"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (`^`) ou "qualquer coisa que não seja número" (o `[^` significa que [não quero o que vem depois](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), ou seja, não quero `0-9` - nenhum dígito de zero a 9).

E no final há `([^0-9]|$)`: qualquer caractere que não seja número **ou** o final da string (`$`). Isso garante que não pegará casos como `112/10/2019`. [Veja aqui](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ravpd8SN1wXRnrzTVBdYdQ/1) a diferença.

Em outras linguagens e *engines* é possível usar `\b` em vez de `(^|[^0-9])` e `([^0-9]|$)`, mas o MySQL não suporta isso.

---

Antes do MySQL 8 não havia `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, então é um pouco mais complicado. Se a data estiver logo no início da string, dá para usar a [solução proposta pelo Luiz Fernando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/360864/112052). Mas se a data estiver em qualquer posição da string, acho mais fácil extrair os dados usando alguma linguagem de programação e manipulá-los lá (pois as linguagens geralmente possuem mais recursos de regex que o MySQL, que é [bem limitado](https://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html)).

---

#### Datas x Regex

Apenas um adendo sobre o uso de regex para verificar datas. A regex `[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}` aceita valores que não são datas válidas, como `99/99/9999` e `00/00/0000`, [veja aqui um exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/VnMrWl/1). Isso porque `[0-9]` significa "qualquer dígito de `0` a `9`".

É possível melhorar um pouco usando algo como:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)[0-9]{2}
```

Isso garante que os dias só podem ser de 01 a 31, os meses de 01 a 12, e os anos de 1900 a 2099.

Mas ainda sim, esta regex aceita datas como 31/04/2019 (sendo que abril só tem 30 dias) e 29/02/2019 (29 de fevereiro em um ano não bissexto), [veja](https://regex101.com/r/VnMrWl/2). Não ficou claro como os dados são inseridos no seu banco, mas pode ser que ocorra um erro de digitação, ou simplesmente uma data inválida apareça no meio da string.

Até é possível ter uma regex que verifique essas condições. [Nesta pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15491894) há alguns exemplos, mas eles são tão complicados que começa a não valer a pena. Veja uma delas, só para ter uma ideia:

`^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$`

<sup>*Entendeu? Eu também não.*</sup>

Lembrando que `\d` não é suportado pelo MySQL, então você deve trocá-los por `[0-9]`. Mesmo assim, na minha opinião não vale a pena usar essa regex. Ela é um problema para entender e para manter futuramente (boa sorte para quem tiver que alterá-la e adicionar novos casos, por exemplo).

É preciso achar um equilíbrio. Usar a regex gigante acima garante que não serão retornadas datas inválidas, mas é um pesadelo de manutenção. Usando as expressões sugeridas no início desta resposta, você obtém trechos que **parecem** uma data (pode acertar na maioria dos casos, mas também trará algumas datas inválidas, algo que você deve avaliar se é aceitável). Uma vez extraídos estes trechos, uma validação adicional poderia ser feita posteriormente, de preferência usando alguma API de datas (ou seja, extraia estes dados do banco e faça a validação usando sua linguagem de programação favorita).

Regex é uma ferramenta poderosa, mas [não é uma solução mágica que resolve todos os casos](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: foda demais, obrigado.