# Validação de formulário utilizando regex e JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validação

Estou com dificuldade para validar meu formulário, estou tentando validar com JavaScript, só que atá agora não consegui validar todos os campos.

Ele só valida o campo que está por último no código. Por exemplo, no código, ele valida o nome, mas não valida o telefone. Estou fazendo ele tudo junto, HTML junto com o JavaScript:

```js
  function formatar(mascara, documento) {
    var i = documento.value.length;
    var saida = mascara.substring(0, 1);
    var texto = mascara.substring(i)

    if (texto.substring(0, 1) != saida) {
      documento.value += texto.substring(0, 1);
    }

  }


  function validar() {
    value = document.getElementById("nascimento").value;
    re = /^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/;
    if (re.test(value)) {
      document.troca.submit();
    } else {
      alert('Data de Nascimento Inválida');
      form.nascimento.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }


  function validar() {
    value = document.getElementById("cpf").value;
    re = /([0-9]{2}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\/]?[0-9]{4}[-]?[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[-]?[0-9]{2})/g
    if (re.test(value)) {
      document.troca.submit();
    } else {
      alert('CPF Inválido');
      form.cpf.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }


  function validar() {
    value = document.getElementById("tel").value;
    re = /^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{4}/g;
    if (re.test(value)) {
      document.troca.submit();
    } else {
      alert('Telefone Inválido');
      form.tel.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }


  function validar() {
    value = document.getElementById("nome").value;
    re = /^[a-zA-ZéúíóáÉÚÍÓÁèùìòàçÇÈÙÌÒÀõãñÕÃÑêûîôâÊÛÎÔÂëÿüïöäËYÜÏÖÄ\-\ \s]+$/;
    if (re.test(value)) {
      document.troca.submit();
    } else {
      alert('Nome Inválido');
      form.nome.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <title>Cadastro</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico" />
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <!--===============================================================================================-->

</head>

<body>

  <div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-login100">
      <div class="wrap-login100">
        <form class="login100-form validate-form" action="cadastro.php" method="POST" name="form" id="form" onsubmit="return validar();">
          <span class="login100-form-title p-b-26">
      Cadastrar Cliente
     </span>

          <div class="wrap-input100 ">
            <input class="input100" type="text" name="nome" id="nome" required autocomplete="off" />
            <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Nome"></span>
          </div>

          <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Telefone inválido">
            <input class="input100" type="Tel" name="tel" id="tel" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="13" minlength="13" OnKeyPress="formatar('##-#####-####', this)" />
            <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Telefone"></span>
          </div>

          <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Email inválido">
            <input class="input100" type="email" name="email" id="email" required autocomplete="off" />
            <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="E-mail"></span>
          </div>

          <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Data inválida">
            <input class="input100" type="text" name="nascimento" id="nascimento" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" minlength="10" OnKeyPress="formatar('##/##/####', this)" />
            <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Nascimento"></span>
          </div>

          <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="CPF inválido">
            <input class="input100" type="Tel" name="cpf" id="cpf" autocomplete="off" required maxlength="14" minlength="14" OnKeyPress="formatar('###.###.###-##', this)" />
            <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="CPF"></span>
          </div>

          <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
            <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
              <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
              <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn" onclick="return validar()">
        Confirmar
       </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

        <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
          <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
            <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div><a href="painel.html"><button class="login100-form-btn">Voltar</button></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>

  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <script src="vendor/animsition/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <script src="vendor/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <script src="vendor/countdowntime/countdowntime.js"></script>
  <!--===============================================================================================-->
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `button type="submit"`, você chama a função `validar()` quando o botão é clicado (`onclick="return validar()"`). Mas depois, no `onsubmit` do `form`, chama a função de novo. Então a primeira coisa é remover uma dessas chamadas. Podemos remover do `button` e deixar somente no `form`.

Em seguida, você define várias vezes a função `validar`. Com isso, a função é sobrescrita e [vale somente a última definição](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33973987) (no caso, a que valida o nome). Veja um exemplo do que aconteceu no seu caso:

```js
function validar() {
  alert('validar 1');
}
// criando a mesma função de novo
function validar() {
  alert('validar 2');
}
// e de novo
function validar() {
  alert('validar 3');
}

// o alert chamado será "validar 3"
validar();
```

Ao chamar a função `validar()` acima, será exibido um alerta com o texto "validar 3". Isso acontece porque eu defini a função 3 vezes, e a terceira vez sobrescreve as anteriores. Foi o que aconteceu quando você definiu várias vezes a sua função `validar()`.

Para evitar este problema - e até mesmo organizar o código - você deve mudar os nomes, indicando o que cada função valida (por exemplo, `validarNome`, `validarCPF`, etc), e em seguida ter uma função que valida tudo, ou seja, que chama todas essas funções.

Outro detalhe é que você não precisa chamar `submit()` dentro destas funções. Colocando a chamada da validação no `onsubmit` do `form`, basta retornar `true` ou `false`, [indicando se o formulário será submetido ou não](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35037069).

No exemplo abaixo eu dei uma "limpada" no seu HTML (retirei as classes CSS, etc), apenas para focar no mecanismo da validação em si.

```js
function formatar(mascara, documento) {
  let i = documento.value.length;
  let saida = mascara.substring(0, 1);
  let texto = mascara.substring(i);

  if (texto.substring(0, 1) != saida) {
    documento.value += texto.substring(0, 1);
  }
}

function validarDtNasc() {
  let value = document.getElementById("nascimento").value;
  let re = /^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/;
  if (!re.test(value)) {
    // campo inválido, retorna false para o formulário não ser submetido
    alert('Data de Nascimento Inválida');
    document.form.nascimento.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function validarCPF() {
  let value = document.getElementById("cpf").value;
  let re = /([0-9]{2}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\/]?[0-9]{4}[-]?[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[-]?[0-9]{2})/g;
  if (! re.test(value)) {
    // campo inválido, retorna false para o formulário não ser submetido
    alert('CPF Inválido');
    document.form.cpf.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}


function validarTel() {
  let value = document.getElementById("tel").value;
  let re = /^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{4}/g;
  if (! re.test(value)) {
    // campo inválido, retorna false para o formulário não ser submetido
    alert('Telefone Inválido');
    document.form.tel.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function validarNome() {
  let value = document.getElementById("nome").value;
  let re = /^[a-zA-ZéúíóáÉÚÍÓÁèùìòàçÇÈÙÌÒÀõãñÕÃÑêûîôâÊÛÎÔÂëÿüïöäËYÜÏÖÄ\-\ \s]+$/;
  if (!re.test(value)) {
    // campo inválido, retorna false para o formulário não ser submetido
    alert('Nome Inválido');
    document.form.nome.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

// valida todos os campos
function validarTudo() {
  // se um deles for inválido, retorna false e o form não é submetido
  return validarNome() && validarTel() && validarDtNasc() && validarCPF();
}
```

```html
<form name="form" id="form" onsubmit="return validarTudo();">
  <div>
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" required autocomplete="off">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="tel">Tel:</label>
    <input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="13" minlength="13" onkeypress="formatar('##-#####-####', this)">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required autocomplete="off">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="nascimento">Data Nascimento</label>
    <input type="text" name="nascimento" id="nascimento" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" minlength="10" onkeypress="formatar('##/##/####', this)">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
    <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" autocomplete="off" required maxlength="14" minlength="14" onkeypress="formatar('###.###.###-##', this)">
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type="submit">Confirmar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Repare também que para declarar as variáveis troquei `var` por `let` - [veja aqui a diferença](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/112052) entre eles.

---

#### Sobre as validações

Quanto às validações em si, é importante ressaltar alguns pontos.

A regex do nome aceita vários espaços. Preencha o campo com somente espaços e verá que ela considera válido. Ela também aceita nomes sem sobrenome (escrever somente "João" é válido, cabe a você verificar se isso é realmente válido ou não no seu sistema) Talvez [algo assim](https://regex101.com/r/H9m60i/1) seja mais preciso, avalie se precisa de algo tão complexo ou deixe para fazer uma validação mais precisa no [*backend*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/112052).

No CPF, é interessante validar também os dígitos verificadores, dê uma olhada [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51340/112052) para mais detalhes (e faça algumas buscas no site e na internet de modo geral, o que não falta são exemplos para você se basear).

Sobre as expressões regulares, você pode usar `\d`, que é um sinônimo de `[0-9]`, conforme descrito na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters). Ou seja:

```
// em vez dessa
let re = /^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/;

// pode usar essa
let re = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/;
```

Sobre o uso de regex para validar datas, eu comento um pouco [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363711/112052) e na segunda metade [desta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/360903/112052), e também há exemplos [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/272539/112052). Mas talvez seja melhor seguir a recomendação [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272541/112052) e em vez de regex, usar os recursos da linguagem que são específicos para tratar datas, como o próprio objeto [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (também há [vários exemplos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20Date) no site) ou até mesmo uma lib específica, como o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/).

E se quiser, também pode mudar o campo para `input type="date"`, não esquecendo de verificar a [compatibilidade dos browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) (e a documentação [sugere um *workaround*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Handling_browser_support) para os browsers que não suportam este tipo de `input`).

E não se esqueça também de [validar todas essas informações no *backend*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/112052).

Answer (score 0):

1. Separar seu código em JavaScript/HTML pode ajudar bastante para desenvolvimento futuro
2. No seu HTML, o tratador para o "click" é `onclick="return validar()"`. Sua função validar é:

```js
function validar() {
    value = document.getElementById("cpf").value;
    re = /([0-9]{2}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\/]?[0-9]{4}[-]?[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[-]?[0-9]{2})/g
    if (re.test(value)) {
        document.troca.submit();
    } else {
        alert('CPF Inválido');
        form.cpf.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Está sendo verificado somente o CPF. Claramente, você teria que alterar seu código para verificar cada campo de entrada, e manualmente você terá um grande trabalho, sem contar o esforço pra manter esse código. Dê uma olhada em *frameworks* que 
podem te ajudar; sugiro olhar links como https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ e http://form.guide/jquery/validation-using-jquery-examples.html