# Regex para um ano YYYY válido em java?

Tags: java, regex, data

Estou utilizando estas expressões regulares para uma futura verificação de datas:

```
Pattern padraoDia = Pattern.compile("([1-9]|0[1-9])|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]");
Pattern padraoMes = Pattern.compile("(0[1-9]|[1-9])|1[0-2]");
Pattern padraoAno = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{4}");
```

Assim, faço a verificação através do `if` para executar o que desejo:

```
if (padraoDia.matcher(dia).matches() && padraoMes.matcher(mes).matches() && padraoAno.matcher(ano).matches()) {}
```

`dia`, `mes` e `ano` são strings. Acontece que, se a string `ano` for `"8052"` ele vai validar como `true`. Tem como eu definir no meu regex um intervalo de anos, por exemplo 2000 a 2030?

Comment: E por que fazer essa validação no REGEX? Não seria mais simples tratar o valor em si?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Tem como eu definir no meu regex um intervalo de anos*

Até tem, mas não vale a pena.

Regex trabalha basicamente com texto, e mesmo dígitos são tratados como meros caracteres, sem levar em conta o seu valor numérico. Para verificar se a string contém um número, e se este está em determinada faixa de valores, é mais fácil converter a string para número. Algo assim:

```java
public static boolean anoValido(String ano) {
    try {
        // converte a string para número
        int valorAno = Integer.parseInt(ano);
        // verifica se o valor está na faixa de anos válidos
        return 2000 <= valorAno && valorAno <= 2030;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // se quiser, não precisa imprimir mensagem nenhuma, só retorne false
        System.out.println("Valor do ano não é um número");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Se a string não for número, ele cai no `catch`, e aí você pode decidir como tratar a exceção (imprime mensagem de erro, apenas retorna `false`, ou deixa a exceção estourar removendo o `try`/`catch`, e quem chamou o método que se vire para tratá-la, etc).

---

## Um jeito melhor

Se quer validar a data como um todo, é melhor tratar a combinação dia/mês/ano, em vez de validar cada um separadamente. Isso porque nem toda combinação é válida: tem meses que não tem 31 dias, tem fevereiro em anos bissextos, etc. Ou seja, mesmo se o dia for 31 (que é válido), nem sempre será uma data válida, pois depende do mês (e até mesmo do ano, caso seja dia 29 de fevereiro).

Sendo assim, melhor usar uma API de datas, que já tem todas essas validações prontas.
**A partir do Java 8**, você pode usar a [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052):

```java
public static boolean dataValida(String strDia, String strMes, String strAno) {
    try {
        int ano = Integer.parseInt(strAno);
        // se o ano é válido, tenta criar a data
        // se o ano for inválido, nem tento converter o dia e mês
        if (2000 <= ano && ano <= 2030) {
            // converte as strings para números
            int dia = Integer.parseInt(strDia);
            int mes = Integer.parseInt(strMes);
            // tenta criar a data, se der certo retorna true
            LocalDate.of(ano, mes, dia);
            return true;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException | DateTimeException e) {
        // imprime mensagem de erro? Não faz nada?
    }
    return false;
}
```

Ou seja, se o ano está no intervalo desejado, eu tento criar a data, usando um `java.time.LocalDate` (esta classe já verifica se o mês tem 31 dias, se é ano bissexto e fevereiro pode ter 29 dias, se algum valor está fora da faixa - como por exemplo mês maior que 12, valores negativos, etc). Se a data for inválida, ele lança um `DateTimeException`, e se alguma string não for um número, o código lança um `NumberFormatException` (e ambos caem no `catch`, retornando `false`).

---

Um detalhe é que assim ele acaba aceitando valores como `"0001"` ou `"1"` (e o método `parseInt` converte todos para o número `1`). Mas se a ideia é que as strings devem ter **exatamente** uma determinada quantidade de dígitos (dia e mês sempre com 2 dígitos, ano sempre com 4), uma alternativa é usar um `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`:

```java
public static boolean dataValida(String strDia, String strMes, String strAno) {
    try {
        // dia e mês sempre devem ter 2 dígitos, ano deve ter 4 dígitos
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMuuuu")
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
        LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse(strDia + strMes + strAno, parser);
        int ano = data.getYear();
        // verifica o ano
        return 2000 <= ano && ano <= 2030;
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        // imprime mensagem de erro? Não faz nada?
    }
    return false;
}
```

Assim você usa a ferramenta correta para o seu problema (uma API de datas para validar uma data). Com regex pode até "funcionar", mas não é o mais indicado.

---

Para Java <= 7, você teria que usar a API legada (`java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar` e `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`):

```java
public static boolean dataValida(String strDia, String strMes, String strAno) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false); // não aceitar valores inválidos
        Date date = sdf.parse(strDia + strMes + strAno);

        // pegar o ano
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        int ano = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        return 2000 <= ano && ano <= 2030;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

O detalhe é que `SimpleDateFormat` por padrão é leniente e [aceita "qualquer coisa"](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue172-Wonky-Dating.html), então precisamos fazer `setLenient(false)` para que ele só aceite datas válidas.

A ideia é similar: primeiro tento criar a data. Se deu certo, verifico o ano. Se a data for inválida, cai no `catch` e retorno `false`.

---

#### Quer mesmo usar regex?

Eu já disse que não é para usar, mas se quiser **muito**, a princípio *seria* assim:

```java
Pattern padraoAno = Pattern.compile("20([0-2][0-9]|30)");
```

Ou seja, começa com `20` e depois tem duas possibilidades:

- `[0-2][0-9]`: um dígito de zero a 2, seguido de um dígito de zero a 9 (isso cobre os valores de `00` a `29`), ou
- `30`: o número 30

Assim, ele pega anos de 2000 a 2030.

Mas como eu já disse, ainda sim isso não valida a combinação dia/mês/ano: não verifica se o mês pode ter dia 31, ou se é ano bissexto (para caso o mês seja fevereiro, precise saber se pode ter 29 dias), etc. E para fazer tudo isso, você precisaria de uma regex [bem mais complicada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8768241):

`^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:0?2(\/|-|\.)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$`

Quer mesmo usar isso? Eu recomendo que use a API de datas e esqueça regex (sobre o uso de regex para manipular/validar datas, leia mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/363660/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/360903/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/272539/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/245172/112052)).

Regex pode até ser legal (eu particularmente gosto bastante), mas [nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: Muito obrigada pela resposta!